# How to programmatically create pause in Windows Service app?

Tags: c#, windows-services, delay

I am creating a Windows Service app that I would like to have programmatically pause when either a system error, odbc connection, or missing file error occur while . I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this? The Windows service app uses an odbc connection and datareader to connect to an MS Access database and an Oracle table, so there are the probable errors that I would be handling with those, I just want to allow a pause for the user handle the errors if/when they occur.

Comment: Just a reminder, windows services are usually ran without a UI and without user interaction.  Pausing your service to wait for user interaction would be an anti-design pattern you want to avoid.  A better solution would be to have some sort of notification mechanism for errors.  Something as simple as the event log or as sophisticated as an MSMQ pub/sub pattern for listening to server events.  Then you can create a UI around the notification and not adversely impact any users of your service.

Comment: I agree. This is probably not a good design. If you have to do it however, for whatever reason, You can do so as I posted below.

Comment: Your question can't really be answered as it stands since services don't have UI. If you can explain how you are interacting with the user (most likely with a standard desktop app that communicates with the service) then the question will make more sense.

Comment: Most if not all communication for this service will be done via Oracle which recieves the data from service that calls the data from MS Access. I would like to correct myself, I agree mentioning user interaction is counter-intuitive. SRM, you are spot on, I just could put the words together at the time. I would like a way to notify for errors. Thank you all for your help. I will definitely look into you method, Jonathan.

Comment: @Dante. I have written a signaling system which uses a socket to send messages back and forth between processes. You can then have a thread in your UI program that notifies the user of the error asynchronously. Would you like me to show you how to do it?

Comment: I am not sure if it is bad design. Think of a service which synchronizes information from one source to another. Lets say the destination is no longer available (internet disconnected). Then it might be good to add an entry to eventlog and then pause the service. If the problem can only be solved by a user but should nearly never occur - this sounds quite nice. If you assume that the internet connection comes back in time, is might be nicer for the service to wait 5 minutes and then try again - and maybe only log a warning.

Comment: @Jonathan. That would be great.

Comment: @dante I will write a blog post on my blog and then put a link here. It is rather lengthy, but not very complicated.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If this works then I should be able to get this project running in a matter of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second
```

Adjust the 1000 to 1000 times however long you want it to sleep in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutValue);

service.Pause(); //or whatever you want here.
sevice.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Paused, timeout);
```

...

Then to restart, do the same thing except for

```
 service.Continue();
 sevice.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
```

You can do this for any state you want. Check out the msdn documentation by googling SeviceController. It will be the first result returned.

Also, you will need to handle the OnPause and OnContinue events in your service.

Comment: I guess this controls _another_ service. What about let the service stop itself?

Comment: A service can stop itself. Just put this code in your service. Of course, it can't start itself, but you can most certainly stop a service.

Comment: I guess in this design, you could have the service pause itself when it has an exception. Then the GUI user could hit a button to continue the service when they are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your service has a continual loop that checks for data, add a check to an external source for pause/continue commands. This source can be a message queue like MSMQ or a database table.

I implemented something along like this by having my service continually check a table for commands, and reporting its status in another table. When it gets a start command it launches a processing loop on another thread. A stop command causes it to signal the thread to gracefully exit. The service core never stops running.

The user interacts via a separate app with a UI that lets them view the service's status and submit commands. Since the app does its control via a database it doesn't have to run on the same machine that the service is running on.